# Evitar cache de imagem de fato, não apenas alterar o nome do src

Tags: php, javascript, cache

Tenho uma imagem que é carregada múltiplas vezes, cada vez com um conteúdo que não será reutilizado. 
para esse problema, encontrei várias respostas sugerindo algo

```
var d = new Date();
buff.src="carrega.php?ver="+d.getTime();
```

Ou com número aleatório.

outras sugerem:

```
<meta Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
<meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-directive: no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Cache-directive: no-cache">
```

Bom, 
a segunda solução simplesmente não funciona. E se funcionasse seria para a página inteira e eu quero desabilitar o cache de uma imagem só.

A primeira não é uma solução. Ele me retorna imagens diferentes, até aí ok. Mas, a cada vez que eu carrego, a imagem fica armazenada em cache, que é o que eu quero evitar para não carregar o uso de memória (são muitas imagens carregadas durante uso muito longo). Também não quero ter que recomendar o usuário a limitar o espaço de armazenamento de cache. Isso não seria solução do problema, também.

Comment: Só desabilitar o cache pelos cabeçalhos HTTP

Comment: tentei isso, de desabilitar o cache pelos cabeçalhoes http da imagem com:
header("Pragma-directive: no-cache");
header("Cache-directive: no-cache");
header("Cache-control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

e não funciona. Continua armazenando sempre que a imagem é atualizada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma é via arquivo `.htaccess`, adicionando o código:

```
<filesMatch "nome_da_imagem\.(jpg|png)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Irá evitar o cache de arquivos `jpg` e `png` com um nome fixo. Caso queira apenas `jpg`, basta alterar a regex para:

```
"nome_da_imagem\.jpg$"
```

Caso queira evitar o cache de qualquer arquivo `jpg`:

```
"\.jpg$"
```

Testando no Chrome usando o aplicativo ChromeCacheView (CCV):

1. Primeiro vou limpar o cache do Chrome e abrir o CCV. Veja que está vazio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Vou abrir uma página que contém apenas uma imagem `1.jpg` e atualizar a janela do CCV:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que cacheou vários arquivos (.js, .html etc.) mas não cacheou a imagem `1.jpg` que possui na página.

Agora vou remover o código do `.htaccess`, limpar o cache do Chrome e reabrir a página. Ao atualizar a janela do CCV, desta vez a imagem aparece cacheada (`1.jpg`):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]