# Atualizar as imagens salvas no cache

Tags: asp, cache, img

Tenho um cliente que esta com um protelam em seu site de anúncios, pois ao substituir uma imagem a mesma não é atualizada devido ao cache salvo nos navegadores. 
O site foi feito em ASP. E já utilizei algumas técnicas como

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

E

```
<%
Response.addHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" ' HTTP 1.1.
Response.addHeader "Pragma", "no-cache" ' HTTP 1.0.
Response.addHeader "Expires", "0" ' Proxies.
%>
```

Sem nenhum exito.

Comment: Uma forma é adicionar um timestamp no final do nome do arquivo, precedido de um `?`, algo tipo: `imagem.jpg?20190311175900`, que seria o ano + mês + dia + horas + minutos + segundos... desta forma a imagem nunca terá o mesmo nome e não será puxada do cache

Comment: Uma forma tb é alterar o arquivo .htaccess, conforme indicado nesta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/353571/8063